# Using RegEx to split and then truncate lines in a list

Tags: c#, wpf, regex, list, split

I've been struggling with this for hours now, and granted I have issues with RegEx anyways, but no matter what I can't seem to find my error.  My purpose is to be able to have portions of lines that are on the clipboard stripped out, pasting only the remaining portion into various textboxes.  The format on the clipboard is:

> Heading: Information
>
> Heading: Information
>
> Information
>
> Heading: Information
>
> etc,etc,etc

I need only the information to remain, stripping the Header, colon, and whitespaces off.  The code I have thus far is:

```
string[] lines = null;
object obj = this.Parent;
StackPanel parent = (StackPanel)obj;
ChildControls ccChildren = new ChildControls();

if (Clipboard.GetText().Contains('='))
{
}
else if (Clipboard.GetText().Contains(':'))
{
    string filterLabels = @"(?!\:)([^\:]*)$";
    lines = Regex.Split(Clipboard.GetText(), "\r\n");
    List<string> linesList = new List<string>(lines);

    foreach (string line in linesList)
    {
         Regex.Replace(line, filterLabels, "");                    
    }
}
else
{
    lines = Regex.Split(Clipboard.GetText(), "\r\n");
}
```

The RegEx in `filterLabels` I got from playing with RegExBuddy, and according to that it should work fine.  But in reality it doesn't strip anything at all.  Anyone catch something I'm missing?

Comment: Isn't the filter string wrong? For example the ? is a quantifier. To search for the character ? you'd need to have \\? instead of just ?

Comment: When `?` is used at the beginning of a group (i.e. after an opening parenthesis) it means "make this a noncapturing group". He's not actually trying to search for `?` characters, he's telling the engine to ignore the first group.

Comment: Why not filter (Regex.Replace) before you split?

Comment: Is the headling label a static value or does it change?

Comment: you may want to refactor the `Clipboard.GetText()` into one call at the beginning of the block

Comment: That regex just does not make sense to me.  The first part is ignore \: then the second part is not \: Why not just strip Heading: at the beginning and then strip the spaces in two regx statements.

Comment: I think ! after the ? makes it a not.  Any thing not \: is non capturing.

Comment: I think you need @"\r\n" on the split.   And you do know the @ on filter will cause the \ to go to regex.

Comment: The heading is going to be different depending on the groupbox this is running in.  And where would I place the \r\n in the regex?  I couldn't figure that part out (as I said, regex  and I have serious issues:p)

Comment: Dude you are also have trouble with English.    "I think you need @"\r\n" on the split."  First get the split working.  Clearly there are examples on how to use regex to split based on end of line.

Comment: Yeah, I was reading it on my phone and was thinking of only one regex, not two.  Forgot to scroll back up and look at it again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized I never accepted an answer on this, and I thought I'd post my final solution for anyone else that has a similar problem.  Ultimately I took bits and pieces from several of these answers, and came up with this:

```
private void MultiPasteArrayGenerator()
    {
        string[] lines = null;

        if (Clipboard.GetText().Contains('='))
        {

        }
        else if (Clipboard.GetText().Contains(':'))             //Strips headers from skip tools run through Agent Toolbox
        {                
            string filterLabels = @"(?:\w+\s?)*\:(?:\s?)*";           //Set up RegEx statement

            List<string> replacedLine = new List<string>();
            List<string> brokenLines = new List<string>();

            lines = Regex.Split(Clipboard.GetText(), filterLabels);  //Divide text on clipboard into one string per line
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                brokenLines.Add(line);
            }
            brokenLines.Remove("");
            string[] broken = brokenLines.ToArray();
            MultiPaste(broken);
        }
        else
        {
            lines = Regex.Split(Clipboard.GetText(), "\r\n");
            MultiPaste(lines);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`String` is immutable, `Regex.Replace(line, filterLabels, "");` will not modify original `line`.

Read more about `String` on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> A String is called immutable because its value cannot be modified once it has been created.

Try this

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
foreach (string line in lines)
  list.Add(Regex.Replace(line, filterLabels, ""));                    
lines = lineList.ToArray();
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable in C#. When you use a function like `Regex.Replace` it doesn't alter the original string, it creates a new one. `Regex.Replace` returns the altered string, and you need to do something with it.

In this case it looks like you want to alter your original collection of strings. You might be tempted to change it like this...

```
foreach (string line in linesList)
{
    line = Regex.Replace(line, filterLabels, "");                    
}
```

But that will not work because you can't alter collections that you're iterating over with a `foreach` loop (for various complicated reasons). Instead you'll have to use a classic `for` loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < linesList.Count; i++)
{
    linesList[i] = Regex.Replace(linesList[i], filterLabels, "");                    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First think you should try is  `line = Regex.Replace(line, filterLabels, "");`

Or even better:

```
List<string> linesList = new List<string>();

foreach (string line in lines)
{
      lineList.Add(Regex.Replace(line, filterLabels, ""));                    
}

lines = lineList.ToArray();
```

Comment: That will not compile -- you can't alter `foreach` iteration variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex.Replace(line, filterLabels, "");
```

should be

```
replacedLine = Regex.Replace(line, filterLabels, "");
```

as [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/taz3ak2f.aspx) doesn't do replacement inline.

You could also try in single call and get rid of looping

```
string str = Clipboard.GetText();
string filterLabels = @"^.+: ";
string replacedStr = Regex.Replace(str, filterLabels, "", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```